# openOrCreateDatabase error

Tags: android

```
public class DBActivities {
    private final String tableName = "Table_SMS";
    private final String CREATE_TABLE_SMS = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(" + "db_date TEXT " + "db_sms_count INTEGER);";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBActivities() {
        DoDBInitialization();
    }

    private void DoDBInitialization() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(tableName, 0, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    }
```

I'm getting the error "The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type DBActivities". What can be the problem here? DBActivities class is being used by the main class for all database related activites.

I did some research and I tried using:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase(tableName, null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Still the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic java error.  You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

openOrCreateDatabase(...) is not defined in your code.

see this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

You probably want to extend SQLiteOpenHelper with something like this:

```
private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DbHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //called when the version of the existing db is less than the current
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "Upgrading db from "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Comment: Realized that using SQLiteOpenHelper is a better approach. It is the one that is recommended more.